# Minimize Row Locking in an Update with Subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, locking

I've got a SP (Percona 5.6) which is doing an Update with 3 Subselects. Each Subquery is doing a Count with different filters. So basically the SP is

```
UPDATE table1
SET column1 = (SELECT count FROM table2 ...),
SET column2 = (SELECT count FROM table2 ...),
SET column3 = (SELECT count FROM table2 ...);
```

I detect some Deadlocks when the SP is running and some Rows in *table2* gets updated.

Therefore I try to figure out how to minimize the Row Locking Time for *table2* during the SP. What happens if I pull out the Subqueries, eg

```
SET @count1 = (SELECT count FROM table2 ...);
SET @count2 = (SELECT count FROM table2 ...);
SET @count3 = (SELECT count FROM table2 ...);

UPDATE table1
SET column1 = @count1,
SET column2 = @count2,
SET column3 = @count3;
```

I'm aware that this can cause inconsistency, but in this case this is ok. Will this change something regarding the locking time? I'm not sure if the whole SP is running as one transaction. Will this change the performance?

Answer (score 0):

Try `SET tx_isolation = READ-UNCOMMITTED` for the duration of the SP.

Is `SELECT count...` really `SELECT COUNT(*) ... WHERE ...` and it hits lots of rows?  Or is it just hitting one row?

Is there only one row in table1?  Or did you leave off a WHERE clause?

(I am worried that you over-simplified the question; this could lead to getting irrelevant advice.)